# How do I convert a List in Java 8?

Tags: java

In Java 8, I can write

```
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<Integer> intList = strList.stream().map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and that is pretty short already, but I have lots of these conversions and I wonder why the following is not possible, i.e. why is there no convert/transform method?

```
// won't work, as List has no convert() or transform() method:
List<Integer> intList = strList.convert(s -> Integer.valueOf(s));
```

If the implementation of `convert` would be clever, it could maybe even be lazy, so that the conversion is only done when the elements will actually be requested.

Alternatively, I could of course write it myself, but does anyone maybe know a library that provides a method?

```
// any idea which library provides this util?
List<Integer> intList = SomeLibraryUtil.convert(strList, s -> Integer.valueOf(s));
```

Comment: If you switch to c#, there's this set of features called linq that can do such conversion easily

Comment: I would suspect this is because it was easier to define a single new method for the Collection interface to return the new Stream type, and add all the map, filter, reduce functions to that new type, than to add default methods for each one to Collection. Remember that default interface methods are required for older Collection implementations to participate in the new API.

Comment: What @TomG said: adding as many of the new features as possible through a single interface simplifies matters...to say nothing of tricky subtle choices like "what `List` implementation your `convert` method would use."